# Ruby Unique combinations of 2 from n arrays of different sizes

Tags: arrays, ruby, combinations, arrayofarrays

I have an array of *n* arrays all potentially of different sizes.  I need to calculate the possible combinations of 2 by using no more than one value from each array and print the total number.  For example:

I have:

```
n = 3, in arr[n]
arr = [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

I want to get:

```
[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8],
[1, 8], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8],
[3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], 
[4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], etc.

return number of arrays
```

Mathematically, I believe this is x*y + x*z + y*z or:

```
arr[0].size * arr[1].size + arr[0].size * arr[2].size + arr[1].size * arr[2].size
```

Feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken on that formula.

Anyways, how can I achieve this for an unknown *n* arrays?

Comment: I'm not following your formula, how are you deriving `[0,2],[0.3]` etc

Comment: 0 is a value of arr[0], 2 is a value of arr[1], 3 is a value of arr[1].  So I need to pull no more than one value from arr[0], no more than one value from arr[1], and no more than one value from arr[2] to create combinations of two values. So no combinations of arr[0] and arr[0], nor arr[1] and arr[1], etc.  And I need to do this for a variable n in arr[n].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Arrays

You can use [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-combination) and Cartesian [`product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-product) :

```
arrays = [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

p arrays.combination(2).flat_map{ |a, b| a.product(b) }.sort
#=> [[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8]]

p arrays.combination(2).flat_map{ |a, b| a.product(b) }.sort
#=> [[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8]]

p arrays.combination(2).flat_map{|a,b| a.product(b)}.size
#=> 26
```

Calling `combination(2)` on the array outputs all the unique pairs of sub-arrays.
For each pair of arrays, every element of the first array is matched with every element of the second array (see [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)).

[`flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) is here to avoid getting an array of arrays of arrays.

## Size

#### Using combinations

Your formula is correct for 3 sub-arrays. For `n` arrays, you need to list all the combinations of two sub-arrays, and sum the product of their respective size :

```
p arrays.map(&:size).combination(2).map{|s1, s2| s1*s2}.inject(:+)
#=> 26
```

#### Alternative

Using the fact that the expanded version of `(x+y+z)**2` is

```
x**2 + 2*xy + y**2 + 2*xz + 2*yz + z**2
```

we see that :

```
2*xy + 2*xz + 2*yz = (x+y+z)**2 - (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
```

so

```
xy + xz + yz = ( (x+y+z)**2 - (x**2 + y**2 + z**2) )/2
```

It doesn't look like much of a shortcut for 3 values, but it generalizes to `n` arrays, and helps us avoid `combination` altogether :

```
sizes = arrays.map(&:size)
p (sizes.inject(:+)**2 - sizes.map{|s| s**2}.inject(:+))/2
#=> 26
```